# Silent aleph (no, I mean really silent)

Tags: hebrew, pronunciation, tanach

Please explain what is going on with the letter aleph in certain places in Tanakh (e.g. the second to last word of Devarim 3:12, the first word of Tehilim 34:10) where the aleph contributes neither a consonant nor a vowel sound.  In these instances, the word is pronounced as though the aleph were not there at all.

My Feldheim Simanim Tanakh colors these alephs in gray and quotes the "Mesora Rabta" as saying that there are 48 words that contain an unpronounced aleph.  I would be interested to learn more about this phenomenon.  Why are these silent alephs present at all?  Are there any other Hebrew letters that can be completely silent in this way?

(I'm not familiar with the work "Mesora Rabta", so a pointer to that would also be helpful.)

Comment: Does your list of 48 words include ישמעאל?

Comment: I don't have the list of 48 words, but the Feldheim Tanakh does not mark the aleph in ישמעאל as silent, presumably because the aleph is being used as a vowel, representing the sound of the tzere.

Comment: That is interesting, because I would have thought ישמעאל would be a prime candidate. It is vowelized under the ע, with no mark on the א at all: יִשְׁמָעֵאל

Comment: For those who pronounce the ע, is it pronounced "Yishma'-El" or "Yishma-'El"?

Comment: What do the dash and apostrophe represent?

Comment: Yosef: Regarding the tsere in ישמעאל, my understanding is as follows: Any of the five long vowels can sometimes be written מלא, i.e. appearing as a written letter. For tzere, chirik, and kamatz, when we write in nikudim, we write the nikud before the the letter that represents the מלא vowel. (See ראשי in Bamidmar 28:11 for example of kamatz aleph, and there are abundant examples of chirik yod.) Only for cholam and shuruk do we write the vowel on the letter, generally vav. I'm no expert on this, so I welcome any more accurate information.

Comment: Why are you asking from Devarim 3:12? You don't need to go any further than the first word in the Torah to see an instance of this.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly who you are responding to, but yes the aleph in בְּרֵאשִׁית is a מלא tzere vowel.

Comment: @IsaacMoses, and Sam, my understanding is that the pronunciation is generally accepted as Yishma-'el, with the dash representing the break in syllables, and the apostrophe representing the gutteral 'Ayin.  In other words, It's almost as if the Mem has no letter after it to close the syllable, and the 'Ayin is the start of the final syllable, totally swallowing the Aleph.  So, Sam, does your list include this Aleph that is swallowed by the 'Ayin in Yishma'el?

Answer (score 7):

Basically, it's there because the etymology of the word demands it. In your examples, לראובני is from ראובן, where the א is pronounced; and יראו is from ירא, where (in some forms of the word, such as תיראו) the א is also pronounced. In the forms with silent א, then, it's simply assimilated into the preceding vowel.

Comment: But the question remains why the _alef_ is silent rather than pronounced: for example, I'd expect יראו, an imperative, to have a form like זִכְרוּ, and so be יִרְאוּ. Likewise, ראובני, from ראובן, should "by rights" be רְאוּבֵנִי.

Comment: About יראו - not necessarily: its imperative probably follows the pattern of words like לְכוּ or עֲלוּ (in the latter case the sheva turns into a chataf-patach, because ע can't take a sheva na). So the only difference would be that here the א is preserved in spelling, unlike the ה of עלה.

Comment: About ראובן: in that form the initial sheva is definitely sounded (na), so naturally the following consonant has to be pronounced so as to avoid hiatus. But with לראובני and similar forms, the sheva that should be there is weakened enough that it becomes silent (though it's true that according to the usual rules it should be sounded), and hence the א can be elided and its vowel moved back to the ר.

Comment: לְכוּ, and also שְׂאוּ,‎ קְחוּ,‎ שְׁבוּ,‎ צְאוּ, etc., would imply that the imperative here should be רְאוּ. So maybe I'm wrong that יראו is the imperative? (But עֲלוּ is from a ל״ה root, unrelated to this discussion AFAICT.)

Comment: But ראו as an imperative would mean "see," from the shoresh ראה. So here necessarily the י has to be preserved, unlike in שבו and צאו. (That's why I was thinking of comparing it to עלו - there the ה is silent and indeed disappears altogether, whereas here the א is silent but is still written.)

Comment: By that argument, R'Alex, שבו as an imperative would mean "capture", so the י has to be preserved. The fact is that the same word means different things in Hebrew sometimes, like the way the second-person masculine singular future-tense form of any verb matches its third-person feminine singular future, or the way "stayed overnight" (_lanu_) matches "for us", or "understood" (_banu_) matches "in us". Etc. There's no reason I know of the same word can't be the imperative "see" and the imperative "fear".

Comment: OK, but in all those cases (most of them, anyway) the meaning is clear from the context, because they're different parts of speech. (Though I'll grant that sometimes misunderstandings are possible - see Pesachim 42a about "מים שלנו".) Arguably, you can tell apart the two meanings of שבו from context too (a general isn't going to be telling his soldiers, in the heat of battle, "sit down!"). But if the imperative of ירא were to be ראו, then what would 'ראו את ה mean, "see Hashem" or "fear Hashem"?

Comment: R'Alex, that's a little weak IMO, if you'll excuse me: consider, as you mention, מים שלנו. But even granting that the imperative of ירא can't be ראו, that doesn't explain why it should be like עלו, or for any other reason יְראוּ. (Though I suppose it's no worse than anything else.)

Comment: ראו comes from the shoresh ראה (to see). And לכו from לכה. And עלו from עלה. (And forgive my starting a sentence with the word "And", but the bidi will go crazy if I don't start each sentence with an English word) In all of these, the ה in as the third letter of the shoresh is dropped when the word is put into imperative form. However, יראו comes from the root ירא (to fear), and so the א is not dropped. Ambiguity is between word forms is not a reason why Hebrew decides whether to drop a letter from the shoresh. The shorashim שבה (to capture) and ישב (to sit) both have the imperative form שבו.

Comment: ... and the only way to tell which is which their nikudot and whether they're mil'el or mil'ra.

Comment: R'Chanoch, with respect, I believe that is incorrect. The imperative of שבה and of ישב are both שבו, with identical vowels and stress. Likewise, if לכה is a word in _kal_ (is it?) then its imperative will be the same as הלך's. Normally, a weak-פ root's first letter is dropped in the _kal_ imperative, but יְראוּ is an exception (and I was above asking _why_ it is).

Answer (score 2):

After much research, I believe the Aleph in question is known as a [Quiescent Aleph.](http://books.google.com/books?id=sts8plkbPdEC&lpg=PA13&ots=mquZbPdOZW&dq=%22quiescent%20aleph%22%20examples&pg=PA13#v=onepage&q=%22quiescent%20aleph%22%20examples&f=false)

These take no vowel, are not a consonant, and are not counted when performing syllable division.

They appear in [certain environments in Biblical Hebrew.](http://books.google.com/books?id=9MoMO4n6o20C&lpg=PA25&ots=QSD99AYNCt&dq=quiescent%20letters%20aleph&pg=PA25#v=onepage&q=quiescent%20letters%20aleph&f=false)

Answer (score -1):

The Aleph is originally not a "silent" letter: it had a function as a consonant, known as a glottal stop.

A glottal stop refers to the adduction of the vocal folds closing off the flow of air. If you can think of a cockney saying "I like it alot," at the end of "alot" the T is not pronounced. It's also present before the word apple is said (you can feel the folds close before you begin to say the word.)

So for יְראו, phonetically, it would have been: Yuh-R- GLOTTAL STOP-oo.

For לֵאלֹהֵיהֶם, La-GLOTTAL STOP-Lo-Hay-Hem.

An ayin is not silent either: it functioned as a consonant too: a pharyngeal fricative. That is a little harder to pronounces for an English speaker.

Comment: Can you source this? Based on my understanding this is wrong. While אהוי letters can all function as consonants, they all have the ability to function as [_matres lectonis_](http://enwp.org/Mater_lectionis), meaning they are not consonants but serve to demarcate vowel sounds in an [abjad](http://enwp.org/Abjad). In your two examples here, the א is _not_ pronounced. If it were to be pronounced, that would be demarcated by a shva mark under it as in [Ex 15:11](http://bit.ly/Mbe6sU) נאדר. The א there has a shva and is pronounced Ne-STOP-dar. But in your cases, it's a vowel and is not pronounced.

Comment: In fact, pronouncing יראו as you suggested makes it dangerously similar to יראו (year-oo future plural of .ר.א.ה)

Comment: ...umm...you didn't quote any sources in your answer whatsoever! I'm sorry that wikipedia is the easiest thing to link to online, but I think the data contained within it is accurate enough for our purposes. If you'd like to argue, then please site __any__ source that agrees with you!

Comment: I apologize, I was going to quote wiki myself: I made the point that the Alef IS pronounced: it's a consonant known as the glottal stop. Its use as a vowel and matres lectonis is much later: http://books.google.com/books?id=l9HBsxqOJL4C&lpg=PA83&vq=aleph&dq=%22aleph%20is%20a%20consonant%22&pg=PA7#v=snippet&q=aleph&f=false In addition, all the matres lectonis had their consonant value originally  pronounced with the vowel. STOP does not mean not to make a sound: it means to make the glottal stop. Historically, Hebrew has origins not part of a basic Jewish education.

Comment: Essentially, my point is this: before we say the word "apple," we momentarily close the glottis. You can feel it if you try. In both examples from the poster, that's what is marked by the Aleph. יְראו is the better of the two to really notice this physically. This is a much earlier Hebrew than the one in shul or spoken in Israel today.

Comment: Why do you assume I only have a basic Jewish education?? I know what a glottal stop is and I meant exactly that in נאדר (Ne-GLOTTALSTOP-dar). יראו is a bad example because then the ר has no vowel other than the ו! It's pronounced ye-roo with no glottal stop. Were the א to be consonantal, the ר would need a vowel, even a shva (although that would be probematic given the shva on the י). Many times א is pronounced as a consonant, but this is not one of them.

Comment: I apologize, I shouldn't assume anything about anyone.I am deeply sorry. I think looking at your rendering, we might be forgetting that the vowel shuruk can be written with an Aleph.